# Marshal NOT 0 terminated string

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

I have the folowing unmanaged structure.

```
struct MyNativeStruct_Foo
{   
 char product_name[4];
 char product_model[2];
}
```

And the managed equivalent

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct MyManagedStruct_Foo
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst = 4)]
    public string product_name;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst = 2)]
    public string product_model;
}
```

Unfortunately the stings are not null terminated. All 4 characters for the product name are used. If I define the managed structure with "LPStr" the string have to be 0 terminated.

Is there another way to define the managed structure? It is possible to define a custom Marshaller attribute? Or do you have other Ideas?

Note;
The native structure can not be changed.

Thanks

Amberg

[EDIT]
changed to LPStr (comment Jason Larke)

Comment: Just a note, your C++ declaration uses a `char`, not a `char_t`, so your declaration shouldn't need the `TStr`. Plus you explicitly set the CharSet of the struct to `ANSI` anyway :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change your marshalling to treat the string as a fixed-size array of `bytes`s and then using the `Encoding` class to convert the bytes into a managed string.

i.e

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MyManagedStruct_Foo
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=4)]
    public byte[] product_name;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=2)]
    public byte[] product_model;

    public string GetProductName()
    {
        return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(this.product_name);
    }

    public string GetProductModel()
    {
        return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(this.product_model);
    }
}
```

Not exactly the sexiest struct in the world, but it should be fine for your needs.

Comment: I did some tries with a custom marshaller and the custom Marshaller attribute, because such strings are quite often in different structs. But i had problems to pass the string length to the custom Marshaller.

Your solution will produce some lines of code more but it works great. Thanks

Comment: I haven't ever had the occassion to try out Marshalling a fixed-length string from unmanaged memory, which is why I posted a simple `byte` solution. If i get time tonight I'll try mess around with the struct and see if I can get it done in a nicer manner.